# Asyncio : Waiting for completed task when an exception occurs

Tags: python, exception, timeout, python-asyncio, message

The code has 5 workers working.
Every worker is like this (short code):

```
async def worker(name):   

   queue_item = await queue.get()
   msg = queue_item.message  #<--- first attempt
   #.....#

    try:
        #...get_message fails(timeout)...raise#

    except errors.TimedOutError:
        #Retry to get the message
        msg = await get_messages(queue_item.channel, ids=queue_item.id)  # <-- retry                      

        #in order to process it again I put it in different queue 
        await queue_retry.put(msg)
```

but,
Does the `await queue_retry`  wait for `msg = await get_messages` to complete before to update the queue?

If it doesn't, I don't know what msg It'll put in,  I suspect that it doesn't wait for the new `get_message` and it'll put the the old one.

Comment: Yes, `await get_messages(...)` does wait for `get_messages(...)` to complete before proceeding. If you're not sure, change the variable name to `msg2` or something (in both `await` and `queye_retry.put` lines) to convince yourself that you're not dealing with the old `msg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the `await queue_retry` wait for `msg = await get_messages` to complete before to update the queue?

Yes: `await get_messages(...)` does wait for `get_messages(...)` to complete before proceeding. If you're not sure, change the variable name to emg  `msg2` (in both `await` and `queue_retry.put lines`) to convince yourself that you're not dealing with the old `msg`.